# Angular HTTP call does not seem to work. How can I single out the issue?

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

I am designing a mean stack. I have a working backend, tested with postman. Everything is fine. I have the code below. See that in order to make sure that the problem is from the HTTP call, I have done the call directly, I mean, I have entered the data directly. The call arrives to the backend, I have set a console.log, but the body (i.e., req.body) is empty. I have double checked printing the whole req, there is no information there. Anyone knows what is happening? Since the code below is the last part of Angular to “touch” the data, how come the data does not arrive to the backend, even though the call arrives just fine?

```
  private makeAuthApiCall(urlPath: string, user: User): Promise<AuthResponse> {
    user = { email: "jorge@test.com", name: "jorge" };
    const url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}/${urlPath}`;
    return this.http
      .post(url, user)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as AuthResponse);
    // .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: add the Content-Type in header and check

Comment: Try to discover "Network" tab in the browser. There is a lot of useful stuff. Also, it may be a CORS problem which would appear in browser's console

Comment: In fact, it was working, but I have deleted the JWT token just for fun, and it stopped working after that. I went to application and deleted the token.

Comment: When it is a cors problem, the call is denied. The call is arriving, but the body of req.body is empty

Comment: I have just tested another app that was working, and it still works! I have no idea what is going on!

Comment: Do you have the express body parser set up? https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Comment: Dear Jordan.J.D  thanks a lot, now it works! I am new to Angular, and  I am trying to migrate an app from express to angular as front end. Thanks again!